# Distribute apcahe corvoa windows 10 cause error Either you need a new certificate installed for this app package, or you need a new app

Tags: windows-10-universal, visual-studio-cordova

[image]

i have build ionic apache cordova app using visual studio 2015 , below is my ionic app info

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0

Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.12

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7

ios-deploy version: Not installed

ios-sim version: Not installed

OS: Windows 10

Node Version: v6.9.1

Xcode version: Not installed

according to cordova documentation

> Signing is required for distributing and installing Windows Store
>   apps. **This process is normally handled by Visual Studio when you
>   deploy a package for release**

here is content of my build.json

```
{
  "windows": {
    "release": {
      "packageCertificateKeyFile": "res\\native\\windows\\CordovaApp.pfx"
    }
  }
}
```

and here is output of build in windows explorer
[image]

and here the content of CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.1_x86_Test folder

[image]

i have enabled sideLoading in windows 
[image]
but whenever i run the app i get theis error

[image]

so what is wrong with the app , and how can i distribute it without windows app store .

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> what is wrong with the app , and how can i distribute it without windows app store.

From the error message there is something wrong with your certificate file. Please remake your `.pfx` file following the steps by [How to create an app package signing certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx).

By Cordova App there is something to notice: Please make sure the publisher name is identical with your app's publisher name(it's "[Country Code]=Apache Cordova Team" by default.).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to import this certificate on this machine, please follow these steps:

1. In File Explorer, right click an appx that you've signed with a test cert and choose **Properties** from the context menu.
2. Click or tap the **Digital Signatures** tab.
3. Click or tap on the certificate and choose **Details**.
4. Click or tap **View Certificate**.
5. Click or tap **Install Certificate**.
6. In the **Store Location** group, select **Local Machine**.
7. Click or tap **Next** and **OK** to confirm the UAC dialog.
8. In the next screen of the Certificate Import Wizard, change the selected option to **Place all certificates in the following store**.
9. Click or tap **Browse**. In the Select **Certificate Store** window, scroll down and select **Trusted People** and click or tap **OK**.
10. Click or tap **Next**. A new screen appears. Click or tap **Finish**.
11. A confirmation dialog should appear. If so, click **OK**. If a different dialog indicates that there is a problem with the certificate, you may need to do some certificate troubleshooting.
12. Double-click .appx to install

See also [How to troubleshoot app package signature errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835836(v=vs.85).aspx)